# Mexican visa for Finnish residence permit holder

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork, mexico, pakistani-citizens

I am a Pakistani national working in Finland on a residence permit (Type A), and want to travel to Mexico for holidays.

Do I need a Mexican visa, or am I exempted from that requirement because of my Finnish work permit?

I checked Timatic and it says that passengers with a valid visa issued by Canada, Japan, USA, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member State are exempted from Mexican visa for a maximum stay of 180 days.

So does my residence permit count as a valid visa? Kindly please answer.

**Update** I asked the Mexican embassy in Finland about it and they said that I need a visa as my work permit is not a valid visa.

Comment: Have you asked the Mexican consulate or embassy?

Comment: I haven't asked the embassy yet, but I checked from Timatic and it says this in the following link.https://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/find_visa_requirements/visa_passport_information_results.aspx?NC=PK&NV=Pakistan&DC=MX&DV=Mexico&h=da4cd2694a6e3714beab0282f4acce48dcf45d5

Comment: So your question seems to be whether a residence permit counts as a visa for this purpose.  Perhaps you should edit it to make this clear.

Comment: I have edited the question, as you said.

Comment: Thanks. Is your residence permit a separate card, or is it a sticker in your passport?

Comment: @phoog Finnish permits are cards

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=pk&DE=mx&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=fi&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), which you checked yourself:

> Visa required, except for Passengers with a **valid visa** issued
>   by Canada, Japan, USA, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member
>   State for a maximum stay of 180 days.

**and**

> Visa required, except for Passengers with a **permanent**
>   residence permit issued by Finland for a maximum stay of 180
>   days.

Your residence permit is **not** permanent, and when moving to Finland, you do **not** get a visa (unlike in many other Schengen countries), only a residence permit card.

So, unfortunately, you **do** need a Mexican visa.

Comment: While this conclusion follows from a strict reading of the rules, it doesn't make sense that someone with a *lesser* Finnish benefit (a short-stay visa) and someone with a *greater* benefit (permanent residence) would both be exempted while someone with a temporary residence permit would not. I suspect that this answer is in fact incorrect, and that the rules are poorly stated.

Comment: @phoog Where Schengen residents are visa-exempt for a country, Timatic states "except for passengers with a residence permit". Here it says "except for passengers with a **permanent** residence permit", which it also says on the websites of several Mexican consulates (which isn't even where Timatic gets their info from). Absolutely no reason to express it like unless it is the case, and it's similar in Macedonia btw - short-stay Schengen visas and permanent residence pemits exempt you from a visa, while long-stay visas and temporary residence permits do **not**

Comment: I'm aware of the situation in Macedonia, but Mexico and Macedonia have little in common. I was also skeptical of the situation in Macedonia until I saw a specific statement from a Macedonian official that a temporary residence permit doors not suffice, and I will remain unconvinced in this case as well until I see a similar statement from an official Mexican source.

Comment: @phoog Will a consulate website do?

Comment: @phoog Also even if Timatic's government contact did express it poorly, it doesn't matter, since no one's gonna board OP without the proper documents as stated by Timatic

Comment: A consulate website that explicitly excludes residence permits other than those issued for permanent residence, yes. As for boarding, I suspect that the distinction between "permanent residence permit" and "residence permit" is lost on most airline personnel.

Comment: @phoog "I suspect that the distinction between "permanent residence permit" and "residence permit" is lost on most airline personnel" Not in countries with high English proficiency, in my experience (Finland being one)

Comment: @phoog In any case, I'll send a review request to Timatic, so they'll contact their government source (which is often the country's head of immigration)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56455/discussion-between-phoog-and-crazydre).

Comment: @Crazydre Timatic also says that I need a Finnish permanent residence permit to get e-visa for Turkey, but I have already visited Turkey with an e-visa on my Finnish work permit. https://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/find_visa_requirements/visa_passport_information_results.aspx?NC=PK&NV=Pakistan&AC=FI&AV=Finland&DC=TR&DV=Turkey&h=3dcd259a6598256b6c625f3624b5272711bf0b4

Comment: @Szrana Alright, fair enough. Like I said I asked the Timatic team to investigate this, and will also call immigration at Mexico City airport

Comment: I think the governments always mean "any kind of permit" when designing these laws, but fail to translate it properly. So far I'm not aware of a single country where a residence permit is treated worse than a visa.

Comment: @JonathanReez see the OPs update in the Q. Having seen your objections I have decided to +1 this A as it does appear to be correct.

Comment: @JonathanReez "So far I'm not aware of a single country where a residence permit is treated worse than a visa" Read my comment on Macedonıa