# Can a temporary Dutch resident enter Mexico without a visa?

Tags: visas, paperwork, mexico, indonesian-citizens

I'm an Indonesian in The Netherlands. I have a Schengen visa and also a residence permit, but it is temporary, not permanent.

I want to go to Mexico this year in October but I'm not sure if I need visa. Some Mexican Embassy websites say that, if you hold a Schengen visa or permanent residence of any Schengen countries, you don't need visa. Others say that only permanent residents of Schengen countries (not visa holders) can go to Mexico without visa. Another source says that there's a new rule since May 2016, that Schengen visa holders can also go there without visa, but I don't know how to verify it.

Comment: Related: [Mexican visa for Finnish residence permit holder](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/90960/19400)

Answer (score 2):

Temporary Dutch residence won't do it (it must be permanent), but the Visas Department of the Consulate General of México in San Francisco is specific that your Schengen visa will suffice (emphasis mine):

[General Information](https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/sanfrancisco/index.php/visas-traveling-to-mexico):

> A.      Effective March 1st 2010, all visitors traveling to Mexico either by air, land or sea are required to present a valid (non-expired) Passport or Travel Document from their country to enter Mexico.
>
> B.     With the purpose of facilitating and promoting travel to Mexico, effective May 2016 all those foreign nationals, regardless of their nationality, visiting Mexico for tourism, business or transit are NOT required to obtain a Mexican visa IF they hold a **valid (non-expired) Visa** or Permanent Residence of any of this countries: United States of America, Canada, Japan, United Kingdom or **Schengen area (European Union)**.

Comment: It may be useful to add that even people who don't need a visa to enter Mexico will need a tourist permit.  If driving across the border into Mexico these can be obtained at the INM office at the border - free for less than 7 days, or $20USD for up to 6 months.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, except for Passengers with a valid visa issued
>   by Canada, Japan, USA, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member
>   State for a maximum stay of 180 days

and

> Visa required, except for Passengers with a permanent
>   residence permit issued by Netherlands for a maximum stay of
>   180 days

So you cannot use your residence permit to enter Mexico, but if your long-stay visa (in your passport) is still valid, you can show that to the Mexicans and enter for up to 180 days.